# Numpy replace specific rows and columns of one array with specific rows and columns of another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, scipy

I am trying to replace specific rows and columns of a Numpy array as given below.

The values of array a and b are as below initially:

```
a = [[1 1 1 1]
     [1 1 1 1]
     [1 1 1 1]]

b = [[2 3 4 5]
     [6 7 8 9]
     [0 2 3 4]]
```

Now, based on a certain probability, I need to perform elementwise replacing of `a` with the values of `b` (say, after generating a random number, `r`, between 0 and 1 for each element, I will replace the element of `a` with that of `b` if r > 0.8).

How can I use numpy/scipy to do this in Python with high performance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With **masking**. We first generate a matrix with the same dimensions, of random numbers, and check if these are larger than `0.8`:

```
mask = np.random.random(a.shape) > 0.8
```

Now we can assign the values of `b` where `mask` is `True` to the corresponding indices of `a`:

```
a[mask] = b[mask]
```

For example:

```
>>> a
array([[1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.]])
>>> b
array([[2, 3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8, 9],
       [0, 2, 3, 4]])
>>> mask = np.random.random(a.shape) > 0.8
>>> mask
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False]])
>>> a[mask] = b[mask]
>>> a
array([[2., 1., 1., 1.],
       [6., 1., 1., 1.],
       [1., 1., 1., 1.]])
```

So here where the `mask` is `True` (since `0.8` is rather high, we expect on average 2.4 such values), we assign the corresponding value of `b`.